# Как написать программу по нахождению одинаковых цифр в числе?

Tags: python

Написал программу, по нахождению одинаковых цифр в числе. Не могу найти ошибку
upd нужно просто проверить есть ли повторяющиеся цифры или нет.

```
x = int(input('Введите число:'))

def array(x):
    global a
    a = []
    while x > 0:
        b = x % 10
        a.append(b)
        x //= 10
        return list(reversed(a))


print(array(x))
for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i] == a[i+1]:
        print('да')
        break
    else:
        print("нет")
```

Comment: прежде чем писать программу, нужно составить алгоритм, по которому работает эта программа. Судя по коду ваш алгоритм такой: 1. записываем число задом наперед. 2. Сравниваем попарно две рядом стоящие цифры. Никакой из этих шагов не приблизил вас к цели ни на бит. Хотя случайно может выдать и правильный результат, например, на число 1446 (или на любое другое, где две одинаковые цифры стоят рядом). А смысл первого шага вообще непонятен.

Answer (score 1):

У вас цикл `while` завершается на первой итерации. Уберите отступ перед `return`.

Вторая ошибка заключается в том, что у вас цикл for выполняется `len(a)` раз. Поэтому на последней итерации `a[i+1]` приведет к исключению IndexError. Используйте цикл до `len(a) - 1`.

Ну и сам алгоритм сравнения чисел неверный. Для числа `121` вы не найдете совпадений, т.к. `1 != 2` и `2 != 1`. Можно сравнить длину множества от `a` с длиной `a`. Множество содержит только уникальные элементы последовательности, поэтому, если длины разные, то можно сделать вывод, что какое-то число повторяется.

Избавьтесь от глобальных переменных.

```
def array(x):
    nums = []
    while x > 0:
        b = x % 10
        nums.append(b)
        x //= 10
    return list(reversed(nums))


x = int(input('Введите число: '))
a = array(x)
print('Да' if len(set(a)) != len(a) else 'Нет')
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно решить вопрос просто стандартными структурами. Построить список со всеми символами числа, потом множество этих символов (удалит дубли), если длина этих двух переменных не равна то, очевидно, есть дубли. Предварительно можно проверить, что если кол-во символов в списке больше 10 (столько всего есть цифр) то, очевдно, цифры повторяются.

```
def double_exist(number: int) -> bool:
    list_number = [s for s in str(number)]
    if len(list_number) > 10:
        return True

    set_number = set(list_number)
    if len(list_number) != len(set_number):
        return True
    return False


number = int(input('Введите число: '))

if double_exist(number):
    print('Да')
else:
    print('Нет')
```

Comment: вместо проверки на количество символов в списке можно сразу проверить ``if number > 9876543210``

Comment: @Эникейщик верное замечание, спасибо)

Comment: @Эникейщик, с одной стороны, да, но с другой, если завтра добавится условие, что число записано в системе счисления по основанию `n`, код с магическим числом сразу придется переписывать. :)